# Show line whether it's true or false in JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-services

I have a problem in my programming, I want to show only lines that contain `"flDestaqueSite": "True"` in my JSON. I am using JSON and PHP to make the connection.

I use arraY

```
$info["flDestaqueSite"] = $conv->flDestaqueSite;
```

to do the filtering and:

```
<?php $d=0; ?>
                <!--<?php shuffle($destaques); ?>-->
                <?php

                usort($destaques, function($a, $b){
                    if($a["flDestaqueSite"] ==  $b["flDestaqueSite"] ) return 0;
                    return ($a["flDestaqueSite"] < $b["flDestaqueSite"] ) ? 1 : -1;
                });

                foreach($destaques as $destaque){ ?>
                    <?php
                    //filtra os anúncio que não corresponde aos criterios
                    if(filtroAnuncio($_POST, $destaque)==false) continue;

                    $d++;
                    if($d<=5)

                    {
                    ?>

                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
```

to do the execution.

---

Complete filtering code:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3be43f2447754d614b37ac075218af670aa70647

*Sorry for the writing, I'm not fluent in English, I'm using the translator.*

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: There is no error, I want to add in the array that only shows the JSON line that contains: "flDestaqueSite": "True"(JSON file).

Comment: please post the input JSON string so we may get a better picture and actually run your code over the same data you are running it against.

Comment: can you add your json and expected output to question?

Comment: Added a full code link with the JSON output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right after the sort function you can add

```
$destaques = array_filter($destaques,function($value){
    return $value['flDestaqueSite']==='True';
});
```

this will filter out the elements that are not true. when you foreach the elements, only `"flDestaqueSite":"True"` will be available within `$destaques`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much for the attention!